# Calculate limit in use of integrals.

Tags: integration, limits, summation

Calculate limit in use of integrals:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k+n}{3k^2+n^2+1} $$

Solution:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k+n}{3k^2+n^2+1} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\frac{k}{n}+1}{3(k/n)^2+1 + n^{-2}} = \\
\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\frac{k}{n}+1}{3(k/n)^2+1 +n^{-2}} $$

I want use there approximation by Riemann integrals. But I don't know how to deal with $n^{-2}$

Comment: As $n\to\infty,$ $$\dfrac1{n^2}=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Of source $0$ but it is in sum, so I have doubts if it is correct to ignore that fraction.

Comment: The point is that upper bound of $n^{-2}$ can get arbitrary close to $0$, for sufficiently large $n$. And your limit is $n \to \infty$, so it does not matter from which $n$ you start, you can throw away as many of the initial terms as you want, and the limit won't change. The @user10354138's answer makes this precise by using the $\varepsilon>0$.

Answer (score 4):

For any $\varepsilon>0$ and all $n>1/\sqrt\varepsilon$, we have
$$
\frac{k+n}{3k^2+n^2}\geq
\frac{k+n}{3k^2+n^2+1}\geq
\frac{k+n}{3k^2+(1+\varepsilon)n^2}.
$$
So we have
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x+1}{3x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k+n}{3k^2+n^2+1}\geq\int_0^1\frac{x+1}{3x^2+(1+\varepsilon)}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and now take $\varepsilon\to 0$.